# Anyone knows anything that can encode an asm string in bytes using c++?

Tags: c++, assembly, encode, masm

Anyone knows anything that can encode a string in bytes using c++?
[asmpure](https://code.google.com/archive/p/asmpure/) do it on x86.
I need something similar on x64

I need to convert strings into hexadecimal bytes
i.e.

```
"mov rdx, rax" => 48 8B D0
"add ax, 17h" => 66 83 C0 17
"sub cl, 5Bh" => 80 E9 5B
```

Comment: A compiler converts asm code into bytes. Please explain your problem, Not how You want to solve it.

Comment: I need an assembler at run-time.
asmpure do it on x86, but I need it on x64.

Comment: Your strings aren't assemble-time constants, are they?  Otherwise you can just use inline asm or separately-compiled asm source files.  Do you want to *run* the resulting machine code?  Maybe you want a library like LLVM that will help you JIT?

Comment: I get the string at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

For anyone looking for solution here it is:
http://www.keystone-engine.org/